# how to fix position child widget in row? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make comment card.
There is one problem.
My avatar and button are not fixed when comment height is growing

[image]

I want avatar image and button's position fixed.

How can I make this ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../size_config.dart';

class CommentItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 25,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 1000,
                width: 1000,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/img2.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('123',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17)),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  Text(
                    '. If you want to keep these changes, it is re',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    maxLines: 4,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.blue, // button color
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 8.8,
                    height: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 5,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.person_add,
                      size: SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier * 5.5,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details
it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details
it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

Comment: Hi,  can you provide the related code into your question?

Comment: can you send your code? Actually you may have made the position of  the image fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can make use of Row's crossAxisAlignment property it will arrange the widget inside the row respectively

1. For Center -
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
2. For Top -
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
3. For Bottom -
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the crossAxisAlignment?

```
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it using...
>
> ```
> crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use the Alignment Property of Row
There is two alignment property in Row:

1. MainAxisAlignment
2. CrossAxisAlignment

**MainAxisAlignment** is used for Horizontal Alignment of Widgets and **CrossAxisAlignment** is used for Vertical Alignment.

In your case you need to set:

```
Row(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```